# Simple Havel-Hakimi problem

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I want to know if the given degree sequence is graphical based on the Havel-Hakimi theorem.
5;4;4;3;3;2.
I ended up with 0,0,1. Which would show that the sequence is not grpahical, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. Think about how many odd valency verticies there will be.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial disqualifier there is the odd count of odd-degree nodes.

Your Havel-Hakimi calculation is correct:

$\begin{array}{c}
5&4&4&3&3&2\\
&3&3&2&2&1\\
&&2&1&1&1\\
&&&0&0&1\\
\end{array}$

For a six-node graph with the degree sequence starting $5,4,4,...$ the full-sequence options are:

$5,4,4,3,3,1$
$5,4,4,3,2,2$
$5,4,4,4,4,1$
$5,4,4,4,3,2$
$5,4,4,3,3,3$
$5,4,4,4,4,3$